# why is c++builder2010 code completion so slow!

Tags: c++builder, code-completion, c++builder-2010

why is c++builder2010 code completion so slow!

Comment: ..I mean code auto-completion not comppilation

Answer (score 4):

Code completion uses the compiler. The best way to speed up code completion is to make use of optimized precompiled headers. Try the PCH wizard to build up a good .h file to use as your PCH.

Comment: That is not a solution in some cases. We have a 1M LOC application with precompiled headers. We have to turn of code completion to make c++ builder usable.